# Deploying asp.net 4.0 Web Application with IIS6

Tags: iis-6

We are trying to deploy our web application written in .net 4.0 onto iis6 and keep getting the Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive Parser error.  We have used the aspnet_regiis.exe -iru command to install 4.0 on iis and restart it, seperated the application pools, set the website to use asp.net version 4.0.30319.  It keeps throwing the  configuration error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sounds like asp still thinks that it is a 2.0 application.

in IIS make sure that you have asp.net v4.0 allowed.

You should be able to right-click on the website inside of IIS click on properties and then to the ASP.NET tab and select the ASP.NET Framework version. Make sure that it is on 4, and also make sure that it is on a separate worker process. The worker process will compile itself for the framework version of the first item it compiles. So it could still be compiling a 2.0 site and your new 4.0 site.

Comment: Thanks John, Just an additional info about the first point: "in IIS make sure that you have asp.net v4.0 allowed" to Enable ASP.NET 4.0 on IIS6 open inetmgr >> Web Service Extension >> Select ASP.NET v4.0.X >> Click on Allow on the left side.